# Binary search bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line

I have a script that reads two arrays from a file, one called names and one called grades I need to read a name from the user input that is also in the names array.

Here is the text file

```
David 89
Marvin 95
Rich 75
```

I need to use binary search for each name that comes in and display their corresponding grade. Then keep asking for a new name until the user enters nothing and exit the loop

Here is my code

```
names=()
grades=()

while IFS=" " read -r name score
do                                                                                                                              
  names+=( "$name" )                                                                                                      
  grades+=( "$grade" )                                                                                            
done < $inputfile

continue=0
while [ $continue == 0 ]
do
    if [[ $continue = 0 ]]; then
            echo " "
            echo "Enter a student's name to get their grade: "
            read sName
            echo "Searching for $sName's grade"
            #binary search                                                                                          
    fi
    if [[ $sName -eq "" && $continue = 0 ]]; then
            echo "End of search"
            continue=1
    fi
done
```

I don't understand how to implement this type of search

Comment: First step is to sort the names array lexically while maintaining the association with the grades array - can you simply sort the text file beforehand?

Comment: Yes I could sort them before @Andy if you could show me how it works with the array being sorted already? I can update the question

Comment: Is it part of the requirement to store the names and grades in separate arrays? It seems like that forces you to use an internal format that's more cumbersome to handle than your input. Or is the core of the exercise to do a binary search on a (sorted?) Bash array? Then you can remove everything else from the question.

Comment: As a side note, you're using `-eq` and `=` exactly the wrong way around – `-eq` is for numerical comparison, `=` (or the non-POSIX `==`) is for string comparison.

Comment: An associative array would save the binary search, but maybe as @BenjaminW pointed, this is part of the requirement.